# Spring Data JDBC: Required identifier property not found for a MappedCollection

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

```
class Game(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "game")         <---- unnecessary
    var rules: List<Rule> = emptyList(),
){
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null
}

data class Rule(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "rule", keyColumn = "rule_key")<---- unnecessary
    val ruleValues: List<RuleValue>
) 

data class RuleValue(val value: String)
```

and schema is

```
create table game
(
    id              serial primary key
);

create table rule
(
    id              serial primary key,
    game            long references game (id),
    game_key        integer
);

create table rule_value
(
    id               serial primary key,
    game             long references game (id),
    game_key         integer,
    rule             long references rule (id),
    rule_key         integer,
    value            varchar(256)
);
```

In brief I have a `Game` as the root aggregate. A `game`  has a list (order is important) of `Rules` and a `rule` has a list (order is important) of `rule values`. A `rule value` is just a string for now but may extend in the future.

I have 2 questions:

1) **Required identifier property not found** : When I try to save a game I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com...RuleValue!`
 exception message.

2) **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException** : Why do I need `game` and `game_key` columns in the `rule_value` table? If I don't put them I get `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'game_key' in 'field list'`

I am using Spring Boot version 2.2.5.RELEASE with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` corresponds to `spring-data-jdbc` version 1.1.5.RELEASE

---

**SOLUTION-1: adding ID field into the class**

As @chrylis-onstrike- suggested I added `@Id` fields in all the data classes

```
class Game(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "game")
    var rules: List<Rule> = emptyList(),
){
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null
}

data class Rule(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "rule", keyColumn = "rule_key")
    val ruleValues: List<RuleValue>
) {
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null <---- this is new
}

data class RuleValue(val value: String) {
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null  <---- this is new
}
```

and schema changed to

```
create table game
(
    id              serial primary key
);

create table rule
(
    id              serial primary key,
    game            long references game (id),
    game_key        integer
);

create table rule_value
(
    id               serial primary key,
#    game             long references game (id), <---- removed this
#    game_key         integer,                   <---- removed this
    rule             long references rule (id),
    rule_key         integer,
    value            varchar(256)
);
```

---

**SOLUTION-2: adding composite primary keys into the script**

```
class Game(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "game")
    var rules: List<Rule> = emptyList(),
){
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null
}

data class Rule(
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "rule", keyColumn = "rule_key")
    val ruleValues: List<RuleValue>
)

data class RuleValue(val value: String)
```

and schema changed to

```
create table game
(
    id              serial primary key
);

create table rule
(
#    id      serial primary key, <---- removed 
    game     integer,
    game_key integer,
    primary key (game, game_key) <---- added 
);

create table rule_value
(
#    id      serial primary key, <---- removed 
    game     integer, <---- added 
    game_key integer, <---- added 
    rule_key integer,
    value    varchar(2048),
    primary key (game, game_key, rule_key) <---- added 
);
```

---

**Conclusion**
You need to decide whether your objects are `value object`s or an entity. A value object should probably not have an id field in the class as it's identity is defined by the values it carries. However you need to identify a row in a database table and relate it with it's owner thus you need to create composite primary keys in value objects if you want to persist them on different tables.

Comment: Well? Your `RuleValue` class seems only to have a single property `String value`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- `A rule value is just a string for now but may extend in the future.` and the problem is not it being only a string value.

Comment: That's _exactly_ the problem: Your class doesn't have a primary key, and that's exactly what Spring Data is telling you.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- in all the tutorials such data classes do not have `Id` but the aggregate root why do I need to add and `Id` to a data class?

Comment: Your question is now very long, contains a history, a solution, and another question. It looks more like a discussion.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I believe this post is going to be very beneficial for developers, thanks for the downvote btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Required identifier property not found.

   I agree with @chrylis-onstrike- the error tells you to add a field with `@Id` annotation.
   But I also agree with you: this shouldn't be the case. 
   I'd need at least a full stack trace to understand what is going on. 
   A reproducer would be even better.
   Feel free to create an issue on https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC

   Further investigation on the provided reproducer showed that the problem is caused by the `id` column still being present in the database and being an `identity` column.
   Therefore JDBC does return a value after the insert and Spring Data JDBC tries to set that as an id on the entity and then fails to set that id with the exception mentioned in the question.
2. Why do I need game and `game_key` columns in the `rule_value` table?

   As long as `Rule` doesn't have a dedicated id its primary key is the combination of `game` and `game_key` therefore the reference from `rule_value` back consists of these two fields.

   They shouldn't be necessary when `Rule` has an id.

Comment: about 2- game_key and game were unnecessary, I guess you mixed it up with rule.

Comment: @hevi you are right, I misunderstood the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: I am afraid the `Id` problem is caused by Kotlin spring-data-jdbc interoperability issues.

Comment: I'm afraid this might be correct. Could you create an issue with a reproducer?

Comment: updated the answer with the information gathered from the reproducer.